# VHDL-Switches Proper Code

Tags: button, switch-statement, vhdl

Hello I want to get this done

[image: GDF File Image]
*(clickable)*

And i have written this code,is it correct?
Because my compiler on MAX+PLUS II dont show any mistake...

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY alarm IS PORT
(ON/OFF,MOTION_SENSOR,.LIGHT_SENSOR,.SOUND_SENSOR,.CAMERA_SENSOR,.IP_SENSOR,.TEMPERATURE_SENSOR: IN STD_LOGIC;
SENSOR_SIRINE,SENSOR_LIGHT:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END alarm;

ARCHITECTURE LEITOURGEIA OF alarm IS
BEGIN
if (ON/OFF='1' AND (MOTION_SENSOR='1' OR LIGHT_SENSOR='1' OR SOUND_SENSOR='1' OR CAMERA_SENSOR='1' OR IP_SENSOR='1' OR TEMPERATURE_SENSOR='1')) then
SENSOR_LIGHT<='1';
SENSOR_SIRINE<='1';

ELSE IF (ON/OFF='0' AND (MOTION_SENSOR='1' OR LIGHT_SENSOR='1' OR SOUND_SENSOR='1' OR CAMERA_SENSOR='1' OR IP_SENSOR='1' OR TEMPERATURE_SENSOR='1')) then
SENSOR_LIGHT<='1';
SENSOR_SIRINE<='0';

ELSE
SENSOR_LIGHT<='0';
SENSOR_SIRINE<='0';

END IF

END LEITOURGEIA;
```

Comment: you're missing a semicolon after the `end if`. ON/OFF is not a legal identifier in VHDL, nor are identifiers beginning with periods.  An if statement isn't a concurrent statement.

Comment: not a legal identifier meaning? on/off is an input

Comment: Dude, this isn't VHDL.

Comment: ok so you know the solution of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approximation of what your code would look like as valid VHDL:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alarm is 
    port (
        on_off, motion_sensor, light_sensor,
        sound_sensor, camera_sensor, ip_sensor, 
        temperature_sensor:           in  std_logic;
        sensor_sirine, sensor_light:  out std_logic
    );
end alarm;

architecture leitourgeia of alarm is
begin
unlabelled:
    process (on_off, motion_sensor, light_sensor, sound_sensor, 
             camera_sensor, ip_sensor, temperature_sensor)
    begin
        if on_off = '1' and 
            (motion_sensor = '1' or light_sensor = '1' or sound_sensor = '1' or
             camera_sensor = '1' or ip_sensor = '1' or temperature_sensor='1') then
            sensor_light <= '1';
            sensor_sirine <= '1';
        elsif on_off = '0' and 
            (motion_sensor = '1' or light_sensor = '1' or sound_sensor = '1' or 
            camera_sensor = '1' or ip_sensor = '1' or temperature_sensor = '1') then
            sensor_light <= '1';
            sensor_sirine <= '0';
        else
            sensor_light <= '0';
            sensor_sirine <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end leitourgeia;
```

I indented it, fixed some spelling errors, made things valid identifiers, put the if statement in a process and made the `else if` an `elsif`, plus getting rid of two sets of superfluous parentheses.

It now analyzes, elaborates and simulates.

And so does this architecture:

```
architecture foo of alarm is
    signal alarm_light: std_logic; 
begin
    alarm_light <= motion_sensor or sound_sensor or light_sensor or 
                   camera_sensor or ip_sensor or temperature_sensor;

    sensor_light <= alarm_light;

    sensor_sirine <= '1' when alarm_light = '1'  and on_off = '1' else
                     '0'; 
end architecture foo;
```

Which more closely resembles the referenced schematic image.

And this one even more closely resembles the referenced schematic:

```
architecture fum of alarm is
    signal alarm_light: std_logic;
begin
    alarm_light <= motion_sensor or sound_sensor or light_sensor or 
                   camera_sensor or ip_sensor or temperature_sensor;

    sensor_light <= alarm_light;

    sensor_sirine <= on_off and alarm_light;
end architecture fum;
```

Comment: is it a problem to have the names of inputs,outputs and statements (if,elseif) in uppercase?

Comment: No it's not a problem, regular identifiers and reserved words are case insensitive;

Comment: how inputs know that they are in the same gate without dot?

Comment: VHDL doesn't understand what a gate is without instantiation.  Ports have signals, which are named objects.  An entity and architecture are paired, port signals are made available to an architecture (or any architecture of the same entity).  You instantiate an entity and it's default architecture (last one analyzed) or a specified entity and architecture pair in another entity/architecture pair's architecture.  You need to find a book.

Comment: so this code does exactly the same thing with the graph in image?

Comment: It should.  Look at the last one, architecture fum of alarm, compare it to the schematic.